# Create distinct columns from a column of lists in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a column of lists into distinct columns in a pandas DataFrame.
For example, a column named 'Cities' is given by

```
           "Cities"                        
   0 [Paris, London, Belrlin]             
   1 [Paris, Madrid, Lima]               
   2 [Madrid, Los Angeles]               
   3 [Manchester]
```

Desired Result:

```
           "Cities"                    Paris London Berlin Madrid Lima Los Angeles Manchester  
   0 [Paris, London, Belrlin]          1       1      1      0     0        0            0   
   1 [Paris, Madrid, Lima]             1       0      0      1     1        0            0  
   2 [Madrid, Los Angeles]             0       0      0      1     0        1            0  
   3 [Manchester]                      0       0      0      0     0        0            1
```

Comment: Use `get_dummies`

Comment: Or `MultiLabelBinarizer`